# Adjusting bootsrap rows for mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm using bootstrap to style the page, using standard bootstrap classes like container, row, col-sm-offset-n (to get appropriate spacing). But some of the components look very bad on mobile screen.

I have following bootstrap components on my page

```
container
|------row
        |-----bootstrap panel
|------row
        |-----div which holds error messages
|------row
        |-----a form having a textarea and a button
|------row
        |-----span tag
```

The website looks good on large screen but on smaller screen the textarea within the form gets to the leftmost side of the mobile screen. I want it to be shown in the middle. Similarly the last span tag gets attached to the leftmost side of the mobile screen. I want it to be shown in the middle.

Here is what is looks like on bigger and smaller screens respectively.

Larger Screens

[image: Larger Screens]

Smaller Screens

[image: Smaller Screens]

You can see the problem here [screen size](http://www.rethink-life.com/)

Below is the markup I used

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Say your heart out ...</title>
    <!--<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no'>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/custom.css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/toaster.min.css"/>      

    <script src="/libs/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="/libs/js/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="/libs/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/libs/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="/libs/js/spin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/libs/js/angular-spinner.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>

<body ng-app="mean" ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <toaster-container></toaster-container>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-7">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                <span><b>So what you wanna do before you die ...</b></span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Load messages</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" >
              <div ng-cloak class="row">
                  <div class="spinner" ng-show="formModel.loadingData">
                       <span us-spinner></span>
                        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                       <p style="text-align:center">Loading Awesomeness ... </p>      
                 </div> 

                <div class="col-xs-12">                 
                  <ul class="demo1"> 

                   <li class="news-item" ng-repeat="item in records" on-last-element>
                    <table>
                     <tr>
                     <td>
                      <img height="60" ng-src="/images/{{($index+11) % 10}}.png"  class="img-circle" />                      </td>
                         <td style="">{{item.message}} <span class="text-primary">@{{item.username}}</span></td>
                         </tr>
                          </table>
                        </li>

                    </ul>                    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="panel-footer"></div>              
           </div>
        </div>          
    </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
              <p style="text-align:center" ng-cloak class="alert alert-danger" 
                 ng-show="formModel.messageEmpty">
               Oh gosh ! Really you don't wanna do anything before you are gone !!! ohh... come on 
              </p>

              <p style="text-align:center" ng-cloak class="alert alert-danger"
                 ng-show="formModel.messageTooLong">
                 You are trying to do too many things buddy, just 150 characters !!! 
              </p>

             <p style="text-align:center" ng-cloak class="alert alert-danger"
               ng-show="formModel.usernameEmpty">
                 Looks like you forgot to mention your name !!!</p>

              <p style="text-align:center" ng-cloak class="alert alert-danger"
               ng-show="formModel.usernameTooLong">
                 Sorry we can't handle such a long name, please type a short name !!!</p> 

          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row">

           <form  name="messageForm" 
                 novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="onSubmit()" id="message-box">

               <div class="form-group" >
                  <textarea   class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 " required  
                           ng-model="formModel.message" 
                      style="border:double 4px #2B689D;border-radius: 0.5em;" 
                      rows="3"  id="message" 
                      placeholder="Choose your life's best 150 characters followed by @ and your name, then shoot it.."></textarea> 
                    <br/>  
                   <button style="margin-left: 5px" class="col-sm-1 col-xs-12 btn btn-primary" type="submit">Shoot it</button>
                   <br/>
              </div> 
               <br/><br/>
              <p class="col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-7 alert alert-success" 
                 style="text-align:center">
                 e.g. Will love to go to antarctica for adventure, feels kinda penguin@amy 
              </p>
               <br/>
         </form>

     </div>  


        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            Made with the help of <span style="text-decoration:line-through">5 </span>15 cups of coffee by
          </span>            
          <a style="color:white" href="https://twitter.com/alammahtab08" target="_blank">@alammahtab08</a>
        </div><br/>
       </div>

</div>

<script src="/libs/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/js/toaster.min.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

After comments below added bootstrap classes for small screens col-xs and col-sm

Now it looks as this

[image: No Space between textarea,button and message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and replace below class in your textarea. Refer below image to understand how column class works.

---

[image]

---

```
col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-5
```

---

For spacing problem in mobile view you need to use media query, See the below code.
*You can add your custom class also for button.*

---

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 

    .btn-primary{
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-bottom: 2rem; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vishal can you tell me what should I change in the markup.

Comment: There is a class in your text ares named "col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-5", You need to replace them with "col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-5".

Comment: Thanks @Vishal, after using those bootstrap classes it looks much better , one problem though, there is no spacing between textarea and button and similarly between button and the message below it. How can I add that, I have added some break between these elements and it gets displayed on big screen but on small screen these elements don't have any breaks between them. Please see the edited question and snapshot

Comment: Thanks alot @Vishal, got all my answers.

Comment: Ty @MahtabAlam you can make it confirm answer by click on right if this help.